# Chessboard in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, chess

I'm trying to create 5x5 chessboard in OpenGL. I have been able to design a 5x6, and 8x8 but the code just won't work for the 5x5.
Can someone look over the code and maybe point out where my mistake is as the width just wont change to 5?

Here is the part of the code i seem to have a problem with:

```
void drawScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-2.5*1.5, 0.0, 2.5*1.5);

    for(double j=0.0;j>(-5*1.5);j-=1.5)
    {
        k++;
        for(i=0.0;i<(2.5*3.0);i+=3.0)
        {
            if(k%2!=0)
            {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(i,0.0,j);
                glCallList(_displayListId_blackArea);
                glPopMatrix();

            }
            else
            {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(i+1.5,0.0,j);
                glCallList(_displayListId_blackArea);
                glPopMatrix();

            }
        }
    }
    for(double j=0.0;j>(-5*1.5);j-=1.5)
    {
        k++;
        for(i=0.0;i<(2.5*3.0);i+=3.0)
        {
            if(k%2!=0)
            {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(i,0.0,j);
                glCallList(_displayListId_whiteArea);
                glPopMatrix();

            }
            else
            {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(i+1.5,0.0,j);
                glCallList(_displayListId_whiteArea);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation, please. Also, a description of what "doesn't work" means would be helpful.

Comment: where do you declare k? It should be an int and not a double. otherwise the line: k%2!=0 will not work (due to floating point calculation imprecisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand your problem first. You have to draw odd vs even for black vs white board that means at first row if you draw odd white board then you have to draw even black board and in next row  even white board and odd black board. For completing 5*5 chessboard pattern for white and black board row wise is given below:

```
3*2
2*3
3*2
2*3
3*2
```

But code you provide is for equal number of white and black board so you have to change the logic.Here is the part of code where I used my logic to draw 5*5 chessboard and its works perfectly.

```
for(float j=0.0;j>(-5*1.5);j-=1.5)
{
k++;
//for(i=0.0;i<(4*3.0);i+=3.0)
//{
if(k%2==0)
{
for(i=0.0;i<(3*3.0);i+=3.0){
 glPushMatrix();
 glTranslatef(i,0.0,j);
 glCallList(_displayListId_blackArea);
 glPopMatrix();
 }

}
else
{
  for(i=0.0;i<(2*3.0);i+=3.0){
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(i+1.5,0.0,j);
glCallList(_displayListId_blackArea);
glPopMatrix();
}

}
 //}
}
k=0;
for(float j=0.0;j>(-5*1.5);j-=1.5)
{
k++;
  //for(i=0.0;i<(4*3.0);i+=3.0)
 //{
 if(k%2!=0)
 {
     for(i=0.0;i<(3*3.0);i+=3.0){
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(i,0.0,j);
glCallList(_displayListId_whiteArea);
glPopMatrix();
  }

}
  else
 {
    for(i=0.0;i<(2*3.0);i+=3.0){
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(i+1.5,0.0,j);
  glCallList(_displayListId_whiteArea);
  glPopMatrix();
  }

}
}
k=0;
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I will try this shortly and let you know how it works!

Answer (score 3):

If you have an odd number of columns, your "odd vs. even" for black vs white will go different than if you have an even number. I think the easiest way is to do one loop for all the Squares, and keep a `bool white_or_black` variable that is set to `white_or_black = !white_or_black` at the end of each loop.

There is also a large amount of duplicated code that could be made much simpler by having one loop rather than two.

[I'm not 100% sure what is going wrong in your code, so I'm not sure if this will ACTUALLY fix the problem - but I believe it's a worthwhile improvement].

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that by "the width won't change to 5", you are observing a width of 4 or 6.  Would that be correct?  It's quite likely in that case to be an error due to double-precision arithmetic.

You see, you assume infinite precision in your loops, but it's quite conceivable that `5*1.5` is not the same as adding `1.5` five times.

What you should really do is have an integer loop from 1 to 5 (or 0 to 4), and then multiply that value by your square size to produce a co-ordinate.  It's generally not a good idea to loop over doubles unless you know what you are doing and what can happen.

Another thing that you should PLEASE do is use constants instead of literals.  Instead of peppering your code with the number `5`, why not define:

```
const int BoardWidth = 5;
const int BoardHeight = 5;
```

Then it will be a lot easier to change.

Answer (score 0):

Forget that code, it has bad potential, you should use ints as a counter to create the board. For example:

```
const unsigned BOARD_SIZE = 5;

for(unsigned i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; ++i){
 for(unsigned j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j){
    drawBoardCell(i,j, (i*BOARD_SIZE + j) % 2 == 0);
  }
}

void drawBoardCell(const int row, const int col, const bool isBlack){
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(col+1.5,0.0,row);
  const int callId = isBlack ? _displayListId_blackArea : _displayListId_whiteArea;
  glCallList(callId);
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

That might not work at first try  but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: I would replace `(i*BOARD_SIZE + j) % 2` with `bool isBlack = false;` outside the loop, and `isBlack = !isBlack;` in the inner loop. Not only does it save a bunch of math, but it's also much clearer.

Comment: Yea that is another way, I like to stay concise, I guess for readbility we can do `const bool isBlackSquare = (i*BOARD_SIZE+j) % 2 == 0` inside the second for loop before the function call, but I'd rather not introduce another variable in that scope

Comment: thank you all for your help so far. however, i still have some form of problem with the drawBoardCell arguments. Any suggestion to this pls?

Comment: I keep having the error - error C2660: 'drawBoardCell' : function does not take 3 arguments. Kindly help out pls